# Регистрация на сайте через facebook/google

Tags: facebook, регистрация, стилизация, google-account

Прикрутил к сайту регистрацию через facebook/google/twitter. На эмуляторе для моб.версии открываются пути регистрации для трёх этих же ссылок - адаптивно, но когда открываю уже именно на мобильном устройстве(Android - самсунги разные и еще на нескольких кит.популярных марках) - то лишь для twitter нормально и читабельно открывается ссылка, а для facebook и google стили сломаны: facebook - прижат влево и виден небольшой текст - похоже на респонсив до 100px(когда сжимается всё и уже едва понимаешь что на экране, поскольку сам контент по горизонтали сжимается и начинает обрезать и текст и картинки и т.д.), а для google -  отображается регистрация как будто не прописан вьюпорт(всё очень мелко), но вьюпорт прописан и отрабатывает. + проблема в том, что на уже моб.телефоне я не могу проинспектировать стили(к сожалению нет F12 или ПКМ"исследовать элемент").
Проблема в неадекватном отображении окон для регистрации через ссылки facebook/google на мобильных устройствах.

Answer (score -1):

Для корректного отображения модальных окон при регистрации, я бы посоветовал работать JavaScript SDK данных соц.платформ, где имеется свойство Popup.
Для тестирования проектов (mobile) вы можете использовать ресурс [Responsive test](http://mobiletest.me/)

Comment: на разных эмуляторах пробовал - и на них всё отображается хорошо, но когда именно тестируешь на оригинальном устройстве - всё крашится для facebook и оч мелко для google. Спасибо за ссылочку, но по этому эмулятору - всё хорошо, а в действительности  - все плохо.

Comment: Вы мобильную версию через css responsive делаете? есть возможность дать ссылку?

Comment: ну здесь же саму форму регистрации, когда привязываешь какую-то соц.сеть - не стилизую через css responsive. Я сейчас напроверял на куче разных моб.устройствах, и на большинстве - всё хорошо, по видимому это зависит еще от самого встроенного браузера на моб.телефоне, поскольку FF и хром - нормально.
https://staging.solusse.com

Comment: да в основном такие проблемы бывают именно с встроенными браузерами, т.к у них многое нестандартно сделанно.
В любом случае я советую пользоватся например facebook JavaScript SDK, при котором таких проблем не бывает с различными браузерами! )

Comment: Спасибо. @Arsen